# Get match and unmatch items from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to compare two lists for the matching and non matching elements and print them out. I have tried the below code:

```
list1 = ["prefencia","santro ne prefence"]
```

I'm fetching all the text from a webpage using selenium getText() method and all the text is getting stored in a string variable which is then stored to list2:

```
str = "Centro de prefencia de lilly ac"
list2 = []
list2 = str
       
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
       print("match:", item)
    else:
       print("no_match:", item)
```

Result of above code-

```
match:prefencia
```

Seems like in keyword is working like contains. I would want to search for the exact match for the element present in `list1` with the element present in `list2`.

Comment: By "element", do you mean "word"? What is your expected output? Also, don't use `str` as a variable name

Comment: yes by element i mean word , it can be a word or a group of words

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

At least here you have a problem:

```
list1 = ["prefencia","santro ne prefence"]
str = "Centro de prefencia de lilly ac"
list2 = []
list2 = str
```

Do you want list2 variable to be list. Now you set it as an empty list and on next row it to variable str.

How about something like this (quess what you want to do)

```
list1 = ["prefencia","santro ne prefence"]
mystr = "Centro de prefencia de lilly ac"
list2 = mystr.split(' ') // splits your string to list of words
       
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
       print("match:", item)
    else:
       print("no_match:", item)
```

But if you split your string to list of words you'll never get exact match for multiple words such as "santro ne prefence".